# SonarLint - pass value to @SuppressWarnings for adding info

Tags: java, annotations, sonarlint

How to pass a String variable to an @SuppressWarnings annotation for SonarLint?

I defined in a class `SonarQubeId`:
`public static final String CLASS_NAMING_CONVENTION = "squid:S00101";`
and use it as `@SuppressWarnings(SonarQubeId.CLASS_NAMING_CONVENTION)` to annotate some other class.
However, SonarLint will ignore the suppression.
It works as expected when I use `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S00101")`.

My goal is to make the annotation more comprehensible, i.e. showing what is actually suppressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want  *showing what is actually suppressed*
As a workaround you can add general description [inside](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/suppresswarnings-annotation-examples) and compiler will ignore it, as

```
 @SuppressWarnings("squid:S00101", "This is why I add it").
```

> Undefined warnings have no effect, e.g. @SuppressWarnings(“blahblah”). The compiler will ignore that silently.

Comment: That would be a way to go, but one could as well just add a comment.
A preferred solution would be, where the combination of the squid and the comment/explanation is fixed.